# iOS : Implementing the KTPhotoBrowser API

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

Hi I am trying to use [KTPhotoBrowser API](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser) for my application , but having some issue ,

- When I implement the `SDWebImage` everything works fine ,BUT the gallery view have some problem

1- The thumbnails did not arrange fine , as you see they are out of the screen 
[image]

2- when I tap any of these photos it should open with photo view which I can move , pinch and zoom photos but doesn't do this

3- I am not abale to define UINavigationBar !!! why ?:

SDWebImageRootViewController.m:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , 44);
navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
//navbar.barStyle  = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[self.view addSubview:navbar];
[navbar release];
```

I would be grateful if you have some solution . thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPad support has been less than ideal but it said, it should work on the iPad.
Based on the screen shot, it looks like you're missing a navigation controller.  The current version of `KTPhotoBrowser` requires a navigation controller.  This is why tapping a photo is not pushing to the full screen browser. 
You either need to display `KTThumbsViewController` (or a subclass of it) as the root view controller of a navigation controller or push it until the navigations stack.