# UIApplicationDelegate in Interface Builder with Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

My application is a view-based application. I need to create a `UINavigationController` as my `rootViewController`.

In the former version of Xcode, there was a xib file named `mainWindow` in which we could:

- Connect our `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation to the `UIApplication`'s `delegate` outlet
- Connect a `UIWindow` to the `UIApplicationDelegate`
- Connect a `UIViewController` to the `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` property.

But now (Xcode 4.2) does not create this xib file!

So how can I create a custom `UINavigationController` and connect it to my `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation in InterfaceBuilder?

Here is my code in my `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    SDWebImageRootViewController *root = [[SDWebImageRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    _navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:root] autorelease];

     self.window.rootViewController = _navigationController;

    [[_navigationController navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [[_navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:YES];

    [_window addSubview:[_navigationController view]];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, yes, you still can use IB for this even in the latest version of Xcode, so I'm not sure where you're getting that from.

If you want to know how to specify your application delegate without IB, that's fairly simple:

In your `main` method, simply use your application delegate's class name as the 4th parameter to `UIApplicationMain`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        int retVal =  UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"APPLICATION_DELEGATE_CLASS_NAME");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

In fact, Xcode 4.2 does this for you by default when you create a view-based application from the template (although it doesn't use a static string... which is probably better than my suggestion honestly because it would get refactored if you use the built-in refactoring, etc):

`NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])`

To answer your followup question: `ok , then what should I do ? to connect the UINC outlet in interface ?`

Don't bother.

Still don't believe me? Fine... here's a tutorial... it's FIFTEEN steps! ... and absolutely pointless.

First, create the application:

[image]

Open up `main.m` and replace the fourth parameter with `nil`:

[image]

Create a new xib, or hijack the existing one (which I'm going to do here), and make the File's Owner class `UIApplication`.

[image]

Next, add an `Object` from the toolbox and change the class to your `UIApplicationDelegate` subclass:

[image]

Now, switch back over to the File's Owner and connect the `delegate` outlet to the `UIApplicationDelegate` you added. Remove the `view` reference if you're doing what I did and hijacked the existing xib.

[image]

Now add a `UIWindow` from the toolbox.

[image]

Now add a 'UIViewController`from the toolbox. This is your custom`UIViewController`. If you want a`UINavigationController`or`UITableViewController` just add that instead.

[image]

If using a custom `UIViewController` class, specify the class here:

[image]

Connect the `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` outlet to your `UIViewController`:

[image]

Crack open your `UIApplicationDelegate` interface and make or modify the `window` property to make it an `IBOutlet`.

[image]

Switch into the implementation and remove any "worthless" code that sets up your window and root view controller. (I'm being sarcastic here... this succinct code does everything we are doing here... just programmatically instead of through IB.)

[image]

Switch back to your xib and hookup your `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `window` outlet.

[image]

Now, in your target's deployment info, set your xib as the "Main Interface":

[image]

Done.... pshew!

Comment: +1, but I fear what you have described ironically will be done for real. :(

Comment: Thank you very much !! I wish did this before starting to expanding the app , I done what you did , but 2 issue : 1- when I change The class of File's owner to the UIApplication , a warring icon appears to my outlets and actions, 2- I added NSObject and ... still does not recognize my outlets in app delegate

Comment: @Mc.Lover 1- Yeah, because those aren't outlets on UIApplication, they are outlets on your custom view controller. Get rid of em. You'll have to hook them up to your view controller you add in a later step. 2- After you added the NSObject, you've got to change the class to point to your application delegate. Read the instructions carefully and try to understand what you are doing in each step.

Comment: Hi again , thank you steve you're  so humble , but I done what you exactly did ! after lunching app application receive `SIGABRT`

Comment: @Mc.Lover I don't know how to help without more details.

Comment: Here is my source code 
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/?25o025w4g3z30rz)  which I created and it is my recent situation , based on this question :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768871/ios-implementing-the-ktphotobrowser-api)  I would really appreciated if you solve my problem thank you very much